# Create an Images that hold codes and description

Tags: feature-request, images

I have a simple request for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Please create a Images that can contain a  description or code.

For example:

```
![I want to create some description here or some codes, that can explain what this images can do][1]

[1]: http://images-source
```

The result is:

[image: Description]

---

Currently what we have is *-"The big space in the right side is useless, my question looks long because of that useless space."*

[image]

```
I want to create some description here or some codes, that can explain what this images can do
```

Comment: I could *maybe* get on board with placing **actual text** to the right of an image, but putting more text in images? Just say no.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Just what I said `some` not `more`.

Comment: Questions with images like that don't look long to me.

Comment: Gonna be a limitation in markdown that prevents this.  Not sure if the new spec will allow for controlling text wrapping on images, but am pretty sure SE won't implement this, as they have been historically against mucking with their markdown implementation.

Comment: At what width would it be appropriate to put the text to the right, and at what width would it be appropriate to put the text after? For instance, if the image is 75% of the width of question area, having the text to the right would look worse, IMO.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan When width is 20~60%+ the text will be on the right and if the images is 75%+ the text will be on bottom?

Comment: You may want to put that answer in the feature request/question. I was bringing it up as an illustration of the kinds of things that have to be thought of when implementing a request like this. It's not as easy as "put the text to the right of the image".